# Implementing Options HttpVerb

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

I want to accept options requests from an angular website. Every endpoint (signup, login etc) needs to accept the options http verb.

I will then add the following to the response header.

```
   After += ctx =>
                    {
                        ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                        ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, client-token, content-type");
                        ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
                        ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "30758400");
     };
```

What i dont want to do is add an extra route for every endpoint like

```
    Post[path + "Login"] = x => Login();
    Options[path + "Login"] = x => Login();
```

This would be masses of boilerplate code.

Is there a way i can intercept any options request using a wildcard route so that all my endpoints can accept options requests?

Answer (score 3):

Nancy has implicit routes for `OPTIONS` requests, i.e. a user defined `OPTIONS` route has not been defined. See [`OptionsRoute`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Routing/OptionsRoute.cs) for reference.

If you want custom behavior for `OPTIONS` requests, you could alternatively add a `AfterRequest` hook:

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
{
    pipelines.AfterRequest += ctx =>
    {
        // This will always be called at the end of the request
        if (ctx.Request.Method.Equals("OPTIONS", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, client-token, content-type");
            ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
            ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "30758400");
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not really sure why you would only add CORS headers to `OPTIONS` responses?

Comment: so does it make for me to edit the OptionsRoute class in your link to add the headers i need. Do i need to instantiate this class somewhere? Where does this class hook in?

Comment: That's not a hook. It's Nancy's default handling of the `OPTIONS` verb. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish? Do you want to add the headers to all responses?

Comment: Seems you can let nancy's default options implementation run, and then in your after hook add the headers if the request's method is options.

Comment: if i don't declare an explicit matching route where should i add the after pipeline header adding. Normally i inherit from nancy module in a 'basemodule' where i put all the generic functionality like pipeline wrangling. Then i inherit from the basemodule in all other modules in which the routes are defined.

Which after pipeline is going to fire when no route is explicitly defined for the option verb?

Comment: You can add hooks to pipelines in the bootstrapper ([application pipelines](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Application-Before%2C-After-and-OnError-pipelines)) or in a specific module ([module pipelines](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-before-and-after-module-hooks)). If you want to add headers to all responses, I'd suggest you add add an `AfterRequest` hook in the application pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

so if you need all the headers as i did you can add them the ApplicationStartupmethod in the nancy bootstraper as below. The default nancy behavior will be like a wildcard route on any options request and add these headers to the response.

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
        {


            pipelines.AfterRequest += ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, client-token, content-type");
                ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
                ctx.Response.WithHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "30758400");
            };
        }
```