# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing between https and http?

Tags: ssl, cors

i have a page that is hosted on both HTTP and HTTPS, and it makes a HTTP call with jquery to a local http server on the client computer with the following code:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:1234/Ping";
var ajaxSettings = {
    url: url,
    timeout: 1000
};

return $.ajax(ajaxSettings);
```

the client application has the following headers:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Origin, Content-type

This works great when using http but when using https i get a error.

Is there any way to solve this? (generating a ssl certificate and registering it seems a bit overkill)

Comment: What is the server used?And CORS need to be enabled from server end for https mode.

Comment: well there are 2 servers involved the one that has the javascrip is a IIS server and the second on (installed on the client computer) is NancyFx based.

Comment: You can enable cors using this
http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html






http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658627/is-it-possible-to-enable-cors-using-nancyfx

Comment: The page containing javascript which issues CORS ajax request should have same protocol as used for the CORS request.